# Ubuntu 17.10 - Bluetooth service "inactive (dead)"

Tags: 17.10, bluetooth, bluez

I have all of a  sudden a problem with my Bluetooth on Ubuntu 17.10.

The UI tells me it's Off, and I can still turn it off (which is strange).

Then I tried to purge/reinstall Bluez, and used a lot of commands to activate the Bluetooth service but nothing works...

I have read a lot of threads on multiples forums this morning, if someone want to guide me through a kind of debug process it would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: please post the output of `rfkill  list` and `hciconfig  -a`

Comment: Thank you but, surprise, tonight, after reinstalling Bluez like I said this morning and run a few commands in vain (particulary sudo systemctl start bluetooth / sudo systemctl enable bluetooth few times) , when my computer woke up from the sleep mode tonight, the bluetooth started suddenly to work again... I suspect something was triggered at this precise time, but I don't know why or what did that.

Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

First Type in to know the status of Bluetooth

```
sudo service bluetooth status
```

Then Use systemctl to start the Bluetooth service

```
systemctl start bluetooth
```